# Spring boot migration from 1.5.2.x to 2.3.8: How to handle LocalDateTime stored as byteArray

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I had spring boot 1.5.x and now migrating to 2.3.8.RELEASE.

I have an entity with the field "private LocalDateTime endTime" and in the postgres DB it was mapped to type "bytea".
Now as I have probably newer dependencies, there is the following error from flyway:

```
Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [end_time] in table [stream_info]; found [bytea (Types#BINARY)], but expecting [timestamp (Types#TIMESTAMP)]
```

This appears also, when I'm starting the application with a completly new postgres DB.

Does anyone know what I have to do now? Do I need a converter?
And what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you started with a version of Hibernate that didn't support `LocalDateTime` yet so it was serialized through Java serialization as `bytea`. Now you are using a newer Hibernate version that supports this type and properly maps it to `timestamp`. You only way around is to migrate the data. You will have to read in every row, deserialize the data and write it to a temporary `timestamp` column. After you migrated all data, you can rename the column or drop the `bytea` column in favor of the `timestamp` column. Either way, this will require manual migration effort.

Comment: To add to that: Flyway does not upgrade major versions if they do not follow each other. Be sure to carefully read https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#flyway